# ReferenceError - load class with functions

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following class:

```
class ScheduledContent {

    constructor(knex) {
        this.knex = knex
    }

    getAllContent() {
        let res = knex.select().from('scheduled_content')
        return res
    }
}

module.exports = {
    ScheduledContent
};
```

Within my `main.js` I have loaded the class the following way:

```
const contentService = require('./service/ScheduledContent')
const contentService = new ScheduledContent(knex)
console.log(contentService.getAllContent())
```

However, I get the following error:

> ReferenceError: ScheduledContentist not defined

Any suggestion what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `ScheduledContent` file you've exported an object containing `ScheduledContent` class:

```
module.exports = {
  ScheduledContent
};
```

Change your import using `destructuring assignment` to:

```
const { ScheduledContent } = require('./service/ScheduledContent')
```

Comment: Thx for your answer! Now I get the error message: `knex is not defined`. Is my assignment wrong?

Comment: in your `main.js` do you have `knex` defined anywhere?

Comment: Jup. I am loading it with my database config like that: `const knex = require('./config/database')
`

Comment: And can i know the exports in your `/config/database`?

Comment: My `database.js` file looks like the following: `const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
const knexfile = require('../knexfile')
const knex = require('knex')(knexfile[env])

module.exports = knex
`